# Read/load images with unicode characters in image path (Chinese, Japanese, Korean) with Python OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, encoding

I have a directory of images, each image has a Chinese character in it's name. I am trying to list all the images, loop on the list, read, and display each image.

Images Path is something like that https://github.com/sirius-ai/LPRNet_Pytorch/tree/master/data/test

Using `glob` in **python3.6.9**, images names are like that

[image]

Causing `Segmentation Fault` when I read them with `cv2.imread`

How can I solve this problem?.

Answer (score 4):

One method is to use [`np.fromfile()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) to convert the image to a 1-D `ndarray` then use [`cv2.imdecode()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imdecode) to convert it to the normal 3-D shaped `BGR` image format. Depending on your image format (if it has transparency), you can change the decoding flag. Take a look [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80) for a full list of flags.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

for path in glob.glob("images/*.jpg"):
    # Image is in BGR format
    image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(path, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    cv2.waitKey(1000)
```

[image]

**Note:** It seems to work with any unicode image file (Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Russian, etc.)

Comment: Thank you, it solved save my time. ChatGPT-4 can't even solve this problem expecially when there is Chinese words or special symbols in the image path. Tq.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an `OpenCV` issue, rather it's getting the correct string representation of your file name. We could delve into how all that works, but such issue should be fixed in `python3`, so first: are you *sure* you are using `python3` and not `python2`? I'll follow up if you're sure.

[image: Comparison]

Follow up:
So if you do these two commands, do you also get a Seg Fault?

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sirius-ai/LPRNet_Pytorch/master/data/test/%E4%BA%ACPL3N67.jpg

python3 -c 'import cv2; import glob; print(cv2.imread(glob.glob("*")[0]).shape)'
```

You should get (800,800,3) printed to the screen.

If not, what does `python3 -c 'import subprocess; subprocess.call(["ls"])'`  give you? It could be the files you downloaded just are saved with the "byte names".

Comment: Yes. I am using Python 3.6.9